# Timer и захват AsyncLocals (ExecutionContext)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

На гитхабе в тикетах для corefx и asp.net много обсуждений на тему [захвата AsyncLocal при создании таймера](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/issues/171). [#26071](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/26071) [#26065](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/26065) ....

для решения проблемы рекомедуется использовать такой код ([пример](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Shared/src/NonCapturingTimer/NonCapturingTimer.cs))

Нужны ответы понятными словами на вопросы:

1. Каким образом вообще происходит захват? Хочется понять детали.
2. При каких условиях инициализации таймера происходит захват?
3. Придется всегда использовать NonCapturingTimer (класс из примера)?